# How can i represent date using java language

Tags: java

Want to display this string using java

March 23<sup>rd</sup>, 2012

Here rd is superscript.

Comment: As an object? As a String? As binary? Decimal? Octal?

Comment: What font are you using? How are you displaying this? In a document? In a GUI? This is a very incomplete question by the way making it very difficult to answer.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);

The medium specifies the way you want the format.

Comment: prasun actually wants the DateFormat.LONG  I suspect prasun will have to add the Unicode for the superscript he wants to the string output of DateFormat himself.